# Pushing changes with GitHub Actions from another repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action workflow that updates the version number and pushes the changes.

```yaml
name: Update Version Number

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      branch:
        description: 'Branch to use'
        default: 'develop'
        type: string
      milestone:
        description: 'Milestone to use as version'
        type: string

  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      branch:
        description: 'Branch to use'
        default: 'develop'
        type: string
      milestone:
        description: 'Milestone to use as version'
        type: string

jobs:
  update_version:

    permissions:
      contents: write
      packages: write
      repository-projects: write

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - name: Checkout the code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: myorg/repo1
          ref: "${{ inputs.branch }}"

      - name: Update POM Version
        run: |
          echo "Show current path"
          pwd
          ls -a
          echo "Updating to version: ${{ inputs.milestone }}"
          mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${{ inputs.milestone }}
          mvn versions:set-property -Dproperty=assimbly.version -DnewVersion=${{ inputs.milestone }}

      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git commit -a -m "Update version to ${{inputs.milestone}}"

      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          repository: myorg/repo1
          branch: ${{ inputs.branch }}
          force: true
```

When I trigger this worflow either manually (workflow_dispatch) or from another workflow (workflow_call) then this works. If I however call the workflow from another repo I get the following error:

```
Run ad-m/github-push-action@master
Push to branch develop
remote: Permission to myorg/repo1.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myorg/repo1.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Invalid exit code: 128
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ad-m/github-push-action/master/start.js:30:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5) {
  code: 128
```

The other repo (repo2) is within the same GitHub organization. Both of the repositories are public and the branch allows push directly.

I call workflow of repo1 from the workflow of repo2 like this:

```yaml
  call-repo1:
    uses: myorg/repo1/.github/workflows/update-version.yml@develop
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      branch: 'develop'
      milestone: "${{github.event.issue.milestone.title}}"
```

The called workflow runs. Most actions like checkout, maven etc. work normally. There is only the mentioned permission error on push of the changes. According to the GitHub Documentation:

*When a reusable workflow is triggered by a caller workflow, the github context is always associated with the caller workflow. The called workflow is automatically granted access to github.token and secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN.*

My assumption is that the GITHUB_TOKEN of the caller workflow (repo2) is used, instead of the processing workflow in repo1.

I was able to 'workaround' this issue by using a Personal Access Token. I am looking for a solution that can still use "github-actions[bot]" and let the workflow of repo1 behave the same even though calling it from another repository.

Comment: To access workflow from other repository, go to Repo settings -> Actions -> General. Enable option **Accessible from repositories in the 'myorg' organization** under "Access"

Comment: I think this option is only available in private repositories. I have a public repository. The last option I see is "Workflow permissions".

Comment: You can't achieve this without using a PAT (with the expected scope) between public repositories.

Comment: OK, then I will keep using PAT. I was hoping that there was something like scope: inherit (similar to secrets: inherit), whereby default the scope is used where the workflow is running.